# Is the logical not(!) operator used with an assignment operator to always assign false value to the variable on left side of the assignment operator?

Tags: php, variable-assignment, logical-operators, isset, not-operator

I've following code snippet, please go through it :

```
<?php
    // Top of the page, before sending out ANY output to the page.
        $user_is_first_timer = !isset( $_COOKIE["FirstTimer"] );

    // Set the cookie so that the message doesn't show again
        setcookie( "FirstTimer", 1, strtotime( '+1 year' ) );
?>

<H1>hi!</h1><br>


<!-- Put this anywhere on your page. -->
<?php if( $user_is_first_timer ): ?>
    Hello there! you're a first time user!.
<?php endif; ?>
```

In my coding experience, most of the time I've seen statements like `!isset( $_COOKIE["FirstTimer"] )` with the `if` statement. For the first time in my life I'm observing such statement with the assignment operator.

In the above code I only want to understand what does the statement `$user_is_first_timer = !isset( $_COOKIE["FirstTimer"] );` do?

What is the role of logical not(!) operator in this code line?

Please clear my doubts with good and reliable explanation.

Thank You.

Comment: The single ! just flips a bool value. If `isset( $_COOKIE["FirstTimer"] )` returns true, then the user is NOT first timer in this logic I assume. So what is assigned to $user_is_first_timer is ! + true (=false)...

Comment: Note that the second argument of `setcookie` should be a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By example.

Isset (`isset`: Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL):

```
$foo = '1';
$bar = '';
$baz = null;

var_dump(isset($foo));
var_dump(isset($bar));
var_dump(isset($baz));
var_dump(isset($bat));
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

Not operator:

```
var_dump(!true);
var_dump(!false);
```

Output:

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

Together:

```
$qux = 'something';
var_dump(!isset($qux));
var_dump(!isset($quux)); // Note quux isn't set.
```

Output:

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

So in your example, if the cookie value is not set (!isset), you are concluding they have not visited the site before.

With assignment you can have `$true = !false`.  `$true` here will hold true, not false.